# Cocoa Pods import issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am using Cocoa Pods http://cocoapods.org/ to get many libraries in my project.

I have downloaded ShareKit via Cocoa Pods and now I want to modify few classes in ShareKit library. I have helper in my project. So I want to use this helper in ShareKit, but I can't import any classes to ShareKit classes. I think it is connected to different projects when classes are located. ShareKit classes are in the Pods project and my helper classes are in the my project. So how I can import my classes in this case to some Pods library, for example to ShareKit classes.

Comment: What's in your Podfile?

Comment: pod "ShareKit"
pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.1'

Answer (score 0):

The [ShareKit podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/ShareKit/2.3/ShareKit.podspec) uses [subspecs](http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html#subspec) which allows the maintainers to separate the parts of the larger libraries into separate includes so you don't have to have parts you don't need. For example in the ShareKit spec they separate services

```
s.subspec 'Evernote' do |evernote|
  evernote.source_files = 'Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Evernote/**/*.{h,m}'
  evernote.dependency 'Evernote-SDK-iOS', "~> 1.2"
  evernote.dependency 'ShareKit/Core'
end

s.subspec 'Facebook' do |facebook|
  facebook.source_files   = 'Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook/**/*.{h,m}'
  facebook.dependency 'Facebook-iOS-SDK',"~> 3.5"
  facebook.dependency 'ShareKit/Core'
end
```

So if you only wanted support for Evernote you wouldn't also have to include Facebook. This means in your Podfile you have to specify the subspecs you want.

```
pod 'ShareKit/Core'
pod 'ShareKit/Facebook'
```

This will include the files you need. Just having `pod 'Sharekit'` will not. You can see all the available subspecs in the [repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/ShareKit/2.3/ShareKit.podspec) or in `~/.cocoapods/master/ShareKit/2.3/ShareKit.podspec`

Comment: Now you can simply use pod 'ShareKit', or simply pod 'ShareKit/Evernote'